# Hiding scroll bar causes the body to scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I've noticed that if trying to hide the scroll bar using `overflow:hidden` scrolls the site to the top if this CSS style is used for `html` and `body` elements:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is the jQuery code used:

```
$('#end').click(function(){
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hYNGn/

This happens in all major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Opera...

How can avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: @epascarello I'm talking about the vertical scrolling. It scrolls the page up no matter the content.

Comment: @epascarello in fact. On the mobile phone, (iPhone at least), the scrollbar is over the body and is not "eating" any space.

Comment: I ran it on my portrait monitor and when I ran your code the content shifted up [there was no scrolling available]. I thought that is what you were talking about. I misread the question on scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body has `height: 100%` but the children nodes make him overflow. When you set the overflow to `hidden` result the body back to height: 100% relative to the window so it looks like an scroll.

You can do this to keep the height, but I don't see the point of doing this, and it's bugs the scrollbar on Chrome/Chromium

```
$("html, body").css({
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "height": "auto"
});
```

Comment: What would be the solution you suggest then? Hiding the scroll bar is quite common working with layers and more yet using them on a touch device.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hYNGn/2/

```
$('#end').click(function(){
    var thetop = - $(window).scrollTop();
    $("div.demo").css("margin-top",thetop);
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: It does the work but... that looks more like a cheat than like a proper solution :)

Comment: It's not a cheat - it is a proper solution. I don't see why this would be an issue: in fact, by removing the scrollbar you are disrupting the scroll position of the user because the body height has been reduced to that of the viewport. Upvote for the effort.

Comment: @Terry it's modifying the margin. Then, if I want to go back to normal, I will still having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Alvaro You can simply toggle the margin back to zero when you want to revert to the "normal" state. All the solutions here required toggling back to the normal state anyway.

Comment: @Terry and returning it to 0 scrolls up again the site, which is the same thing I'm trying to avoid but this time on close.

Answer (score 1):

Only set the body to hide the overflow:

```
$('#end').click(function(){
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/hYNGn/5/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#end').click(function(){
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        var bodyElement = $("body");
        bodyElement.scrollTop(bodyElement.height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround your problem would be moving the scroll part to the div instead.

Ad: 
overflow hidden to the body

```
html,body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Ad this:

```
.demo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
}
```

And use this click event:

```
$('#end').click(function(){
 $("div.demo").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```